# NestedScrollView scroll with recyclerview

Tags: android, scrollview, android-recyclerview

I layout a `RecyclerView` in a `NestedScrollView` and I want make the `NestedScrollView` scroll with `RecyclerView`, but this only happens when the recyclerView reach the end, below is my layout code:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
android:id="@+id/lists_frame"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
tools:context="com.example.niuky.design.MainActivity4"
>
    <LinearLayout
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:orientation="vertical"
   >
    <View
       android:id="@+id/header"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="256dp"
       android:background="@color/material_blue_grey_800"
       />

   <View
       android:id="@+id/tabs"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
       android:background="@color/material_blue_grey_950"
       />

  <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
      android:id="@+id/recyclerview2"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:minHeight="700dp"

      />
   </LinearLayout>
</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

This is my runtime view: [image: RecyclerView In NestedScrollView]

Comment: Why are you not using the support `CoordinatorLayout` with `AppBarLayout` and `NestedScrollView` instead?

Comment: @tato.rodrigo First I use `CoordinatorLayout ` with `AppBarLayout ` but I cannot got what I want.Do You have any Idea? Many Thanks!

Comment: @tato.rodrigo what if we don't want to use the design support library? `NestedScrollView` should allow us to do such thing... But, as Google is used to lately, there's no documentation at all.

Comment: @acntwww Hi, I'm going through the same problem at the moment, Have you found a fix for this problem  yet? :)

Answer (score 2):

```
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:id="@+id/nested_scrollbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="fill_vertical"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    android:scrollbars="none" >
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/nested_scrollbar_linear"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

                <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                    android:id="@+id/flexible.example.cardview"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

                <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                    android:id="@+id/list_view"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

and apply `.setNestedScrollingEnabled` to `recyclerview` and set it to **false**

P.s: for Api lower 21 :

`ViewCompat.setNestedScrollingEnabled(recyclerView, false);`

Answer (score 1):

On the RecyclerView `android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false"`